# Data processing is very slow in Django

Tags: python, django

I am actually quite new for web application development. Now I want to build a web service to process some geographic vector data in real-time.

Before I started to develop that web app, I wrote a Python script to do that data processing, and the test shows that the processing usually takes 0.1-2 sec.

Afterwards, I moved the codes of that processing in my web app's service side which is in the Django framework in Python, and I put that process in a view， and then when a uses opens that view in web browser, the code of that process would run and send the result to client-side. However, I found this process in the service side unexpectedly took around 10 mins.

Therefore, my question is why that process becomes so slow when it is moved into the service side's Django framework. I would be very grateful if someone could help me out.

Below is the code of my core view, by now I haven't written a web page to show my result, instead I tried to show the result as string in the browser to have a look at if it works.

```
def web_map(request):
    scale_hierarchy = ['1', '5', '10', '25']
    response_str = ''
    for scale in scale_hierarchy:
        response_str += generate_geojson_of_regenerated_features(scale)
    return HttpResponse(response_str)
```

Comment: You will need to provide more information than that. to get any answers here.  Possibly a little of the code to provide an 'minimm working example   of your program. But - what is the environment to run your django application? Is this problem whle testing, or in a live environment with several concurrent users?

Comment: how are you starting the script ? using a command like `./manage mycommand`? or is it a website running behind some webserver?

Comment: I started the script by the command python manage.py runserver

Comment: It's now a simple service, I run it now in Windows 10 and started the service by command line, and it's not a debug environment.

Comment: It ended up that I switched my geoprocessing library from ESRI ArcPy to GDAL could eliminate this problem.